# 189KB of bad NTFS security descriptors in `/var/log/syslog`

Tags: security, windows-10, ntfs, syslog, windows-subsystem-for-linux

### `/var/log/syslog` periodically filled with 189 KB of spam:

```
Dec  9 09:26:33 alien ntfs-3g[612]: Bad security descriptor for 0x10ba
Dec  9 09:26:33 alien ntfs-3g[612]: No security descriptor found for inode 475409
Dec  9 09:26:33 alien ntfs-3g[612]: Failed to retrieve a security descriptor
Dec  9 09:26:33 alien ntfs-3g[612]: Bad security descriptor for 0x8a6
Dec  9 09:26:33 alien ntfs-3g[612]: No security descriptor found for inode 96744
Dec  9 09:26:33 alien ntfs-3g[612]: Failed to retrieve a security descriptor
```

### Three mounted NTFS drives:

```
$ lsdrv
NAME        FSTYPE LABEL            MOUNTPOINT   SIZE MODEL
sda                                            931.5G HGST HTS721010A9
├─sda4      ntfs   WINRETOOLS                    450M 
├─sda2                                           128M 
├─sda5      ntfs   Image                        11.4G 
├─sda3      ntfs   HGST_Win10       /mnt/d       919G 
└─sda1      vfat   ESP                           500M 
nvme0n1                                          477G Samsung SSD 960 PRO 512GB 
├─nvme0n1p5 ext4   NVMe_Ubuntu_16.0 /           44.6G 
├─nvme0n1p3                                       16M 
├─nvme0n1p1 ntfs                                 450M 
├─nvme0n1p6 swap   Linux Swap       [SWAP]       7.9G 
├─nvme0n1p4 ntfs   NVMe_Win10       /mnt/c     414.9G 
├─nvme0n1p2 vfat                    /boot/efi     99M 
└─nvme0n1p7 ntfs   Shared_WSL+Linux /mnt/e         9G
```

**NOTE:** `lsdrv` is an alias: `lsdrv="lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,LABEL,MOUNTPOINT,SIZE,MODEL"`

`/mnt/e` is special in that both **Ubuntu 16.04.3** and **WSL** (*Windows Subsystem for Linux*) use it to store common scripts that run in both environments. I suspect the error messages are derived from here by `/var/log/syslog` doesn't specify.

Perhaps related: WSL is unable to change permissions of files on `/mnt/e`. The method used is to copy the file to `/mnt/c`, change permissions there then move it back to `/mnt/e`.

Perhaps related: `VcXsrv` was installed to get support for Linux GUI. `ubuntu-deskptop` and `xubuntu-desktop` were both installed in WSL to get `gedit`, `nautilus`, `zenity` and `yad` support, etc.

### /etc/fstab

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p5 during installation
UUID=f3f8e7bc-b337-4194-88b8-3a513f6be55b /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
# swap was on /dev/nvme0n1p6 during installation
UUID=b4512bc6-0ec8-4b17-9edd-88db0f031332 none            swap    sw              0       0
#UUID=D656-F2A8 /boot/efi   vfat    defaults    0   0
# Windows drives C, D & E
UUID=F03ED48E3ED44F6A /mnt/d    ntfs-3g permissions,locale=en_US.utf8         0 0
UUID=5CCC5867CC583E08 /mnt/c    ntfs-3g permissions,locale=en_US.utf8,x-gvfs-show 0     0
UUID=F2C2ACE4C2ACADF3 /mnt/e    ntfs-3g permissions,locale=en_US.utf8,x-gvfs-show 0     0
UUID=D656-F2A8  /boot/efi   vfat    defaults    0   1
```

---

## Results from suggestions

These are the results from suggestions made via comments.

### Run Windows 10 check disk

I ran check disk on all three NTFS volumes. For each volume Windows 10 stated no check was necessary but I ran it anyway with no errors reported. This is the screen used to run the tests:

[image: Windows 10 check disk]

---

### Questions

- Can `inode 475409` be traced to a physical file & path to narrow down which NTFS `/mnt/` has the problem?
- What Linux program is putting security descriptor messages in `/var/log/syslog`?
- Can a debug level be set to turn these messages off?
- Can Windows 10 fix these security descriptors in a single user environment?

Comment: Did you try having windows run chkdsk/scandisk on this drive?  And did you make Windows unmount the volume ( how do you even do that? ) before having Linux mount it?  They can't both mount it at the same time or you'll corrupt it.

Comment: @psusi I researched `chkdsk` and security descriptors and many problems people were having in Windows only environments. Couldn't find anything about dual-boot and/or WSL. When Windows shuts down `fastboot` is disabled so that Linux can mount them. When I reboot, Linux automatically unmounts  all drives including NTFS ones.

Comment: Shut down?  I thought that WSL ran Ubuntu in a virtual machine.  You still don't sound like you have run a chkdsk on the volume.

Comment: @psusi I've just run chkdsk on all three volumes. I ran the GUI version, not the DOS version. Question updated with results (or lack thereof). I'm not sure what you mean by ***Shut down?*** The `/var/log/syslog` is from Ubuntu 16.04 not Windows 10 which doesn't have one. WSL is not a virtual machine, simply a driver over the NTFS File System to run Linux binaries natively without recompiling.

Comment: You run the binaries under Windows though, rather than shutting down and rebooting into a Linux kernel AFAIK.